# Solution for if else and NSString statement

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, nsstring

What NSString do I put for return?
The answer I am looking for is 1 cheese OR 2 cheeses

```
- (NSString *) numberOfCheesesStringWithCheeseCount:(NSUInteger)cheeseCount 
{
    if (cheeseCount == 1) {
        /* WORK HERE, ASSUMING THERE IS 1 CHEESE */
        NSString *phrase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)cheeseCount];
        NSLog(@"%@ cheese", phrase);
    } else {
        /* WORK HERE, ASSUMING THERE ARE 2+ CHEESES */
        NSString *phrase2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)cheeseCount];
        NSLog(@"%@ cheeses", phrase2);
    }

    /*
     (You will learn more about if/else statements in the next checkpoint.)
     */

    return ;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the two NSString declarations and add a single `NSString* phrase;` ahead of the `if` statement.  Assign the `stringWithFormat` results to that, and return that.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
- (NSString *)numberOfCheesesStringWithCheeseCount:(NSUInteger)cheeseCount
{
    NSString *phrase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld cheeses", (long)cheeseCount];
    if (cheeseCount == 1)
    {
        phrase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld cheese", (long)cheeseCount];          
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", phrase);
    return phrase;
}
```

Comment: Dangerous if there's any logic following the if/else clause.

Comment: Yes, just found that this simplest answer! Thanks!

Comment: What's the point of the if/else statement? Both return the same thing.

Comment: @maddy, phrase2 returns cheese as a plural. I’d probably use a ternary operator, but it looks like this is an exercise in constructing conditionals.

Comment: @Hot Licks, i thought (because of the method name) that there will be no other logic but usually you were right.

Comment: @JScarry It does now, after the answer was edited. It didn't when I posted my comment.

Comment: There's no need for a function: NSLog(@"I am eating %d %@ for lunch", cheeseCount, (cheeseCount>1?@"cheeses":@"cheese);

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
- (NSString *) numberOfCheesesStringWithCheeseCount:(NSUInteger)cheeseCount 
{
    NSString *result;
    if (cheeseCount == 1)   
    {
        //No real point in building this string piecewise. It will always be
        //the same thing, "1 cheese".
        result = @"1 cheese";
    } 
    else 
    {
        /* WORK HERE, ASSUMING THERE ARE 2+ CHEESES */
        NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld cheeses", (long)cheeseCount];
    }
    NSLog(@"Result = %@", result);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how I’d do this for real, but in the context of your exercise, this would be a good time to learn about variable scope. What you should do is declare an NSString outside of the conditional. That way, when you assign it or change it in the conditional it retains its value. Then assign the phrase inside the conditionals. After you are done, return the phrase.

```
- (NSString *)numberOfCheesesStringWithCheeseCount:(NSUInteger)cheeseCount
{
    NSString *phrase = nil;
    if (cheeseCount == 1)
    {
        phrase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld cheese", (long)cheeseCount];
        NSLog(@"%@", phrase);

    }
    else
    {
        phrase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld cheeses", (long)cheeseCount];
        NSLog(@"%@", phrase);

    }
    return phrase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly don't see the point in having the whole `if else statement` this can be shortened to just an `if statement`. I'd recommend changing to something like:

```
- (NSString *)numberOfCheesesStringWithCheeseCount:(NSUInteger)cheeseCount
{
    // We setup our string (phrase) already with the value "1 Cheese"
    NSString *phrase = @"1 Cheese"; 

    if (cheeseCount > 1) {
        // If the value of cheeseCount is greater than 1 then we update our value.
        phrase = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld cheeses", (long)cheeseCount];
    }

    // Return our value for phrase.
    return phrase;
}
```

This code reads some much simpler then the whole `if else statement`.